# 400, 401 error not catched by angularjs http interceptor or $http().catch()

Tags: angularjs, http-status-code-401, angular-http, angular-http-interceptors

When writing $http() queries  i  found that nor interceptor configured with 
$httpProvider.interceptors.push('myHttpInterceptor') neither $http().catch() never fired with  401 or 400 error. What is going on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem :there  is an interceptor  already ,  that i  installed but  poorly  configured.
In my  case it was angular-http-auth.
After removing it 401 is catched as it should be.

Comment: So you found an answer to a problem you yourself caused? Why post it here?

Comment: Because SO makes this possible ,  explicitly )

I did it so others  could  find the  answer. There is number  of questions  like this ,  i  just   made the  clear Q and A,   i  think

Comment: I know SO makes it possible. But it's a configuration error that you produced. You don't post question and answers to every bug you manage to produce.

Comment: Ok,  let  me  try  to  explain it.
There is a number of similar questions  on SO and abroad,   and there is no answer good enough for me to  help   with this problem .
I spent significant amount of time  trying  to understand  why there is no event  on failure. So i  made  the answer  available  to  public.
Is this good enough reason  to  post  it here for you?